# SOLR - need to create core dynamically (from php script)

Tags: solr

I have one core defined as my template for creating the rest. I need to create new core from my template examle core. New core configuration will be only slightly different. Schema - the same, data config also the same, except some jdbc connection details (database schema/username/password).

I can make copy my core directory, add corresponding core definition to solrc.xml like this `<core name="NewCore" instanceDir="NewCore" />` and then edit my data config xml file, then restart solr (webapp on tomcat).

It works, however I need all of this to be done automatically from php script. End user will create new page and there should be new core automatically created for it.

What is the best way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr exposes the [CoreAdmin Handler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin), which allows you to do core management through a REST-ish interface.

Use `CREATE` for creating a new core (giving the relevant options where necessary).